# Versioning: [ApiVersion("1")] turns into decimal (1.0) in Swagger?

Tags: c#, .net-core-2.2

I have an .net core 2.2 API where I'd like to have 2 different API versions in my controllers.

```
    [ApiController]
    [ApiVersion("1")]
    [ApiVersion("1-pbi")]
    [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
```

And on each controller method I've assigned which version it should map to.
[MapToApiVersion("1")]

However, when I use [MapToApiVersion("1-pbi")] it works perfectly well, but when I use
[MapToApiVersion("1")] the URL in swagger suddenly turns into a decimal 1.0.
I've tried to find a solution, but with not avail.
Has anyone perhaps encountered this and knows a workaround?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What issue is this causing? What is it breaking?

Comment: Inconsistency, all of the other routes in the project are an int, whereas the routes in the controllers where I had to apply 2 different versions, become a decimal if I set [MapToApiVersion("1")]